# React Query: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I had the following problem. I want to create a `useProfile` hook, but I get this error and I don’t know how to solve it:

```json
[{
    "resource": "/D:/AniMi/animi-next/hooks/useProfile.ts",
    "owner": "typescript",
    "code": "2769",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "No overload matches this call.\n  Overload 1 of 3, '(options: UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.\n      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.\n  Overload 2 of 3, '(options: DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): DefinedUseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'DefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.\n      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.\n  Overload 3 of 3, '(options: UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>, queryClient?: QueryClient | undefined): UseQueryResult<unknown, Error>', gave the following error.\n    Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UseQueryOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.",
    "source": "ts",
    "startLineNumber": 5,
    "startColumn": 29,
    "endLineNumber": 5,
    "endColumn": 42
}]
```

Code `useProfile.ts`:

```js
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { UserService } from '@/services/user.service';

export const useProfile = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery('get profile', () => UserService.getProfile());

  return { profile: data };
};
```

`user.service.ts`:

```js
import { instance } from '@/api/api.interceptor';
import { IUser } from '@/types/user.interface';

const USERS = 'users';

type TypeData = {
  username: string;
  email: string;
  avatar: string;
  banner: string;
};

export const UserService = {
  async getProfile() {
    return instance<IUser[]>({
      url: `/${USERS}/@me`,
      method: 'GET',
    });
  },

  async updateProfile(data: TypeData) {
    return instance<IUser[]>({
      url: `/${USERS}/@me`,
      method: 'PUT',
      data,
    });
  },
};
```

I'm using Next.js 14 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## What does the error mean?

The error suggests that the first argument you are passing is not the correct type. You are passing a string type but the code expects something else.

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'UndefinedInitialDataOptions<unknown, Error, unknown, QueryKey>'.
```

## Solution:

The **query key needs to be an array**. This way you can create a key composed of different data (e.g. if the query depends on some data, you add that variable as a query key in this dependency array):

```
import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { UserService } from '@/services/user.service';

export const useProfile = () => {
  // Change to ['get profile']:
  const { data } = useQuery(['get profile'], () => UserService.getProfile());

  return { profile: data };
};
```

You can learn more about this in the [Query Keys TanStack documentation](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-keys).